# How to group set of users in leanplum A/B testing integrated to android app?

Tags: android, mobile, ab-testing, leanplum

I have integrated the leanplum A/b testing with my Android app and it is working fine. But the problem is, each time when I need to change the users to a different variant (for testing), I need to select each user individually and and change the user in the leanplum portal.

Is there any way to group the users and assign the variants to a whole group of users instead of assigning it individually?

And only 100 users are showing in the portal at any time. How can I increase the number of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had the same doubt,For which i contacted the Leanplum support. And they sent me a mail stating that in the Leanplum only individual user can be changed variant. Group variant changing cannot be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. So is there any way to have more than 100 users on the screen at a time?

Comment: No there is no way to display more than  hundred users. However the user id is know and u can search for the user using that.

Comment: Also wanted to add to the above question, What is user Bucket option and how can we use it?

Comment: 100 users is the default in the users tab when you click on. if you apply a filter, it will give you the total count for that group and allow you to download the full list of users.